# building square in javascript out of numbers and asterisks

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nested-loops

Guys I need your assistance I should accomplish task to make a square using for loop in javascript. But I can't get the exact one. Please help me with that!  Here is an illustration how the final output should look like:

```html
* 2 3 4 5<br>
* * 3 4 5<br>
* * * 4 5<br>
* * * * 5<br>
* * * * *<br>
```

I am trying thi solution ,  but str is multiplying itsef instead of decreasing.

```
var n = 5;
var star = "";
var str = '';
var triangle = "";
for(i = 1; i <= n; i++ ){
    star += "* ";
  for (j = 4; j >= 1; j--){
    str += j + " ";
    triangle = star + str;
}console.log(triangle);
}
```

Comment: How did you try to solve it? What was the problem?

Comment: Is there a reference QA for all those "draw shape with a loop" homework questions? There should be.

Comment: juzraai, I edited question and there is my try now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with the current logic in your code. The first and most noticeable issue is that you initialize the variable str outside the loops, and you are appending characters to it inside of your inner loop. This is giving you an undesired effect because the value of the string is not being reset when you iterate through loops, it is just appending more characters which is 'multiplying itself'. So to fix this first issue, all you have to do is simply move the declaration of the str variable into the outer loop.

```
var n = 5;
var star = "";
var triangle = "";
for(i = 1; i <= n; i++ ){
    var str = "";
    star += "* ";
  for (j = 4; j >= 1; j--){
    str += j + " ";
    triangle = star + str;
}console.log(triangle);
}
```

Now the output of the code looks as follows:

```
* 4 3 2 1 
* * 4 3 2 1 
* * * 4 3 2 1 
* * * * 4 3 2 1 
* * * * * 4 3 2 1
```

Which is still undesired. There are now two remaining issues. The numbers are counting down instead of counting up. And four of them are always displayed. Both of these issues can be fixed with one stone by fixing your inner loop as follows:

```
var n = 5;
var star = "";
var triangle = "";
for(i = 1; i <= n; i++ ){
    str = "";
    star += "* ";
  for (j = i + 1; j <= n; j++){
    str += j + " ";
    triangle = star + str;
}
console.log(triangle);  
}
```

This leaves us with on final error which is that the last line is printed the same as the fourth '* * * * 5' because the line that sets triangle is inside the loop and it is not reached on the last iteration of the loop. Final solution is here:

```
var n = 5;
var star = "";
var triangle = "";
for(i = 1; i <= n; i++ ){
    str = "";
    star += "* ";
  for (j = i + 1; j <= n; j++){
    str += j + " ";
}
triangle = star + str;
console.log(triangle);  
}
```